# How to override Magento model classes with as little copy-paste as possible?

Tags: magento

I want to change a single line of code in a single method in e.g. the class `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`. The easiest way seems to be to copy the entire class file to `app/code/local/...`, but then I have *replaced* the original class, not *overridden* a method.

How can I create a new class that inherits from e.g. `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` and only override one method? And still tell Magento to use my new class instead of the original.

Comment: Create module or add your overrided method to one of used modules. Or, you can edit template file in `app/design`, where your code is calling.

Comment: you should read about class rewrites in Magento, here's link to Alan Storm's blog - http://alanstorm.com/magento_upgrade_rewrite_override

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, but don't know how to rewrite the class mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working code to rewrite product collection:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <reports_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <product_collection>Company_ModelName_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</product_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </reports_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

It should work for `Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')` call.

Yeah and I haven't included the `<config>` tag, I think you should already have even `<global>` one, so I felt it wasn't necessary.

Comment: This should be `reports`, not `catalog` in the XML definitions and factory calls.

Comment: thanks @Jürgen! I missed the fact that it's Reports module product collection, not catalog one. I've fixed the response

Comment: After spending some time debugging, it seems the class in question is not loaded via `Mage::getResourceModel`, but inherited by e.g. `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Ordered_Collection`... Since I want to modify the superclass, does that mean that we're looking at a multiple inheritance kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the rewriting of the model would be...

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <reports>
                <rewrite>
                    <resource_product_collection>Namespace_Extension_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</resource_product_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </reports>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

I've never personally rewritten a resource model though, so I can't swear it will work. It will very much depend on how the collection is getting loaded.